# How to remove keys with Lua script and StackExchange.Redis

Tags: lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

I use StackExachange.Redis to remove keys from Redis DB. It is quite slow to get list by mask `*val*` and delete then.

Looking for sample code that is runable with .ScriptEvaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found. Created following method that returns number of keys deleted.

```
public int RedisPurge(string keyContains)
        {
            var serializer = new NewtonsoftSerializer();
            var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(serializer);

            var mask = string.Format("*{0}*", keyContains);

            var result = cacheClient.Database.ScriptEvaluate("local keys = redis.call('keys', ARGV[1]) for i=1,#keys,5000 do redis.call('del', unpack(keys, i, math.min(i+4999, #keys))) end return keys", null, new RedisValue[] { mask });

            try
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(result.ToString().Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```